# How to prevent asp:Timer from sending tick before response is generated?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, timer, postback

I have an ASP.NET web site. I want a user to make a decision and click one of the given buttons within a certain amount of time and redirect him to another page. If he didn't make a decision, he still will be redirected with "no choice made" mark in my head.

I use `asp:Timer` to initiate postback after time is up. I'm doing redirect by calling `Response.Redirect('page.html', false)` in `Page_Load` handler. In this case I can handle `button_click` or `timer_tick` events before actually redirecting. After one of those events is processed, page is rendered and redirect is done.

But I have two problems. First, if input is processed long enough, second timer's tick is triggered, new postback initiated, and my current is canceled! Second, if user click a button just before the time is up, the timer tick occurs before redirect is done and it again overrides handling of user click!

How can I resolve these issues? How can I disable timer on client side after the first tick is triggered or after a user have clicked a button? Or what is the better way of solving my task? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for both problems.

1. I placed `asp:Timer` inside an `asp:UpdatePanel` control. This is the right thing to do in my case since I don't need to refresh entire page before the next question. But I discovered that in this case ticks from timer don't interfere with each other.
2. As described [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1163588/1929583.aspx), I can disable `asp:Timer` using javascript like this:

   ```
   $find("TimerMaxJudgeTime")._stopTimer();
   ```

   Then I bind this to my buttons' `onclick` event and I'm done. Since timer is placed inside an `UpdatePanel`, it is autmatically recreated and enabled after a postback.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant you may use client-side `setTimeout` function  instead of Timer control and clear timeout on button click:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var redirectTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
           location.href = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/page.html") %>';
      }, 5000);
 </script>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" 
      OnClientClick="clearTimeout(redirectTimeout);" />
```

Comment: If I'm currently on `page.html`, will this call produce a postback? When using `asp:Timer`, I have an `IsPostBack` property set to true after tick is triggered and it is important. Actually, user have to make several decisions on the same page before redirecting to another.

Comment: No, this code doesn't produce a postback. You can add a hidden button and click it from javascript to do postback by timeout. Actually it's not well clear for me reason to do continuous redirects to the page itself. Could you clarify your scenario? You may join a chat to minimize comments amount: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17081/how-to-prevent-asptimer-from-sending-tick-before-response-is-generated

Comment: I added clarification to the chat.